# How can i add custom field in admin side spree_order in Spree eCommerce?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

**I want to add Custom field in *spree_order* table.**

**I'm using spree-3.0 stable and rails 4.2.0.**

Field name is pre_order_id.

Using Strong Params.

Right now It gives Error in console **Unpermitted parameter: pre_order_id**.

I also append **pre_order_id** using below steps.

**This code write in spree.rb**

```
Spree::PermittedAttributes.class_eval do

 class_variable_set(:@@checkout_attributes,class_variable_get(:@@checkout_attributes).push(:pre_order_id))

end
```

But still problem remaining.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to accomplish this by adding to the bottom of my Spree initializer (initializers/spree.rb):

```
Spree::PermittedAttributes.checkout_attributes << [:pre_order_id]
```

Works on my machine. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 3):

To permit custom field in order table you should insert code inside

> app/models/spree/order_decorator.rb

```
Spree::PermittedAttributes.order_attributes.push << :pre_order_id
```

I uses same code in user model to permit parameters.